# Messages in JSON output for a Geoprocessing Service from a Model

Tags: arcgis-10.1, arcgis-server, modelbuilder, geoprocessing-service

I have a Model created from ModelBuilder. It was published as a Geoprocessing Service on ArcGIS Server 10.1

When it was triggered from the REST service, the JSON output printed out the "results" and "messages". The "results" can be configured as derived parameters in ModelBuilder. However, I  couldn't find anywhere that "messages" can be configured.

Is it possible?

Answer (score 1):

If it were a Geoprocessing Service based on a Python Script Tool the messages are what comes from arcpy.AddMessage().

To do the equivalent from ModelBuilder there is nothing out-of-the-box but some discussion has occurred, and there is **[code written by Curtis Price](http://forums.arcgis.com/threads/69376-Message-script-tool-for-ModelBuilder?p=242029)** available.

I recommend you vote for this ArcGIS Idea for a **[Geoprocessing tool for writing messages to the model window](http://ideas.arcgis.com/ideaView?id=08730000000bp9FAAQ)** (like I am about to).